# globally access data across all pages in REACT js

Tags: reactjs

In header react component class have defined function  Search

```
 Search: function()
 { 
   var author=$('#author').val();   
   var bookname=$('#title').val();  
   var isbn=$('#isbn').val();   
   var keywords=$('#keywords').val();   
   var publisher=$('#publisher').val();       
   var url=VDOMAIN+"/aodrbooks.php?action=srch&author="+author+"&isbn="+isbn+"&publisher="+publisher+"&name="+bookname+"&price=''";   
   $.ajax({url:url,                                
       success: function(result){
           resp = JSON.parse(result);   //this data is an array     
             if(resp['count']==1){                
               location.href=VDOMAIN+"odrbooks?pagename=bkd&bid="+resp['results'][0]['bookid']+"&bkname="+resp['results'][0]['name'];
              }
              else{                     
                    location.href=VDOMAIN+"odrbooks?pagename=cat&type=&author="+author+"&bkname="+bookname;
                  }
           }
         });  
  },
```

here how do i make my  **resp** data globally such thAT I can access it in any page in any component?

I tried using `this.state.data=resp` ,`this.props.data=resp` and `this.setState({data:resp})`

Answer (score 0):

Use state container for that purpose. The most popular one right now is https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux

You can dispatch an action and store successful response in Your reducer which represents Your application state.

Then connect that reducer to the component that needs resp data and use it through props.